# Extract Image from a URL using Python 3

Tags: python, url, flask, python-imaging-library, urllib

I'm working on a REST API using Flask in which I have to retrieve an Image from a URL which is provided by the user inside the Url Parameters.

Here's What I have tried:

```
import urllib
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/<path:image_url>')
def build_mask_rmv_bg(image_url):
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(image_url)
    jpeg_str = f.read()
    original_im = Image.open(BytesIO(jpeg_str))
    return original_im


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And, Here my request:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/http://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/models/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/img/image2.jpg
```

I have tried both HTTP & HTTTPs paths in URL Parameter.But it return the following error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2018 09:37:51] "GET /http://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/models/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/img/image2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

**Update:**

I have updated it by using `wget`, now it doesn't return any error but the file is still not downloading the image.

Here's the updated code:

```
from flask import Flask
import wget
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/<path:image_url>')
def build_mask_rmv_bg(image_url):
    url = str(image_url)
    # download the file contents in binary format
    print(url)
    wget.download(url, "img/image1.jpg")
    return 'something happened'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

What's wrong here?

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error

Comment: Hi @dvnguyen, I have tried it but the same error returns back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python request module to get data from URL then save in file in binary format like this

```
f = open(filename, "wb")
r = requests.get(url)
f.write(r.content)
```